# Show Blended Layers reveals red UIImage but it does not have an alpha channel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image that does not have an alpha channel - I confirmed in Finder's Get Info panel. Yet when I put it in a `UIImageView` which is within a `UIScrollView` and I enable Show Blended Layers, the image is red which indicates it's trying to apply transparency which will be a hit on performance.

*How can fix this to be green so iOS knows everything in this view is fully opaque?*

I tried the following but this did not remove the red color:

```
self.imageView.opaque = YES;
self.scrollView.opaque = YES;
```

Comment: I can't edit questions so here's a comment. Instruments has a Core Animation graphics template and one of its options highlights in red layers that are blended into other layers (i.e. they are partially translucent or transparent). Joey would like to know why this happens in the case he outlined and how to fix it. I have a similar problem with GADBannerView that I too would like to fix.

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa Nope

Answer (score 13):

By default, `UIImage` instances are rendered in a Graphic Context that includes alpha channel. To avoid it, you need to generate another image using a new Graphic Context where `opaque = YES`.

```
- (UIImage *)optimizedImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGSize imageSize = image.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( imageSize, opaque, scale );
    [image drawInRect: CGRectMake( 0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height )];
    UIImage *optimizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return optimizedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3x
Xcode 9x

```
func optimizedImage(from image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let imageSize: CGSize = image.size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, true, UIScreen.main.scale)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))
    let optimizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return optimizedImage ?? UIImage()
}
```